Dealing with duplicates in RNA-seq dataset
I am performing RNA-seq analysis using DESeq2 pipeline followed up by other downstream applications such as transcription factors inference in which gene symbols have to be set as rownames.
there are some duplicated gene symbols in my dataset making it hard to be used as row names. in this case, how would you deal with these duplicated gene symbols? would you remove them, take the average, or what would you recommend otherwise?
Thanks in advance!
